# SharePoint Adapter for Breeze JS/Angular and the SP User Information List

Tags: angularjs, sharepoint-2013, breeze

**The Problem**
The SharePoint adapter for Breeze expects a model with a SharePoint list name and then attempts by default to access `_api/web/lists/getbytitle('<DefaultResourceName>')` and I have not found a way to over ride that. The problem with this behavior is that if a user who is not a site collection admin accesses the User Information List using the `web/lists/` end point they will receive a 404 error. Instead, for whatever reason, regular users must access the same exact information via `_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items`.

**The Question**
What would be the best way to add functionality to the Breeze SharePoint adapter to get user details or a list of site users? In my existing solution I have merely changed my data context object to use `$http` and the `_api/Web/SiteUserInfoList/items`end point but I'd like to still be able to use Breeze's amazing filtering ability but it's not clear to me the best path to begin adding this functionality to the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

With breeze you can configure specific AJAX requests using a [**request interceptor**](http://www.getbreezenow.com/documentation/controlling-ajax).

The example below changes the timeout but you could just as easily change the url.

```
var ajaxAdapter = breeze.config.getAdapterInstance('ajax');
ajaxAdapter.requestInterceptor = function (requestInfo) {
    requestInfo.config.timeout = 5000; 
    // todo:  examine the requestInfo.config object and change the url as-needed
}
```

[here's the relevant code in the breeze source](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/blob/22baad83795aa05f274adae25224bda49d016046/src/b00_breeze.ajax.angular.js#L53-L95)